# Unhandled promises error inside array of promises

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code. I make an `writeRecords` request and then I do it again.
The next request I put in an array and use an `Promise.all()`

My question is:

What if `requests.push(writeClient.writeRecords(timestreamParams).promise())` has an error, will it be an unhandled Promise error, or will the `try / catch` catch the error?
Because it's in an loop it can be that the first element in the array has already sent back an response while the other data is still in the loop so I am not sure where the error will occur?

```
let requests = []
  const chunkSize = 100
  for (let i = 0; i < Records.length; i += chunkSize) {
    const chunk = Records.slice(i, i + chunkSize)
    const timestreamParams = {
      DatabaseName: db_name,
      TableName: TimeSpanRawE[table_name],
      Records: chunk,
    }
    await writeClient
      .writeRecords(timestreamParams)
      .promise()
      .catch(() => {}) // Silent error

    // Successfully retry same writeRecordsRequest with same records and versions, because writeRecords API is idempotent.

    requests.push(writeClient.writeRecords(timestreamParams).promise())
  }

  try {
    return Promise.all(requests).then((res) => ok(res))
  } catch (error) {
    return err({ error, params })
  }
```

Comment: "*it can be that the first element in the array has already sent back an response while the loop is still running*" - yes, since you have an `await` in that loop. No, if you don't use `await` in the loop. So: why are you calling `writeClient.writeRecords(timestreamParams).promise()` twice?!

Comment: @Bergi for your question why i do it twice: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/code-samples.write.html#code-samples.write.upserts

I actually also dont know why,they do it in their example too. they just write `Successfully retry same writeRecordsRequest with same records and versions, because writeRecords API is idempotent.`

Comment: They don't do it because it's necessary, they do it in the example to demonstrate what happens when you accidentally write twice with the same versions.

Comment: If any of your write requests go sideways and throw an error, your try/catch around `Promise.all()` will swoop in and catch it. This happens because `Promise.all()` is designed to immediately trip up and reject if any of the promises in its list reject. So, your catch block's got your back!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code can lead to unhandled promise rejections, if one of the promises in the `requests` array rejects before the `Promise.all` is reached (due to the loop being suspended on the `await`). It cannot happen if the loop were run synchronously.

You should be using either the concurrent version

```
try {
  const requests = []
  const chunkSize = 100
  for (let i = 0; i < Records.length; i += chunkSize) {
    const chunk = Records.slice(i, i + chunkSize)
    const timestreamParams = {
      DatabaseName: db_name,
      TableName: TimeSpanRawE[table_name],
      Records: chunk,
    }
    requests.push(writeClient.writeRecords(timestreamParams).promise())
  }

  const res = await Promise.all(requests)
  ok(res)
} catch (error) {
  return err({ error, params })
}
```

or the sequential version

```
try {
  const res = []
  const chunkSize = 100
  for (let i = 0; i < Records.length; i += chunkSize) {
    const chunk = Records.slice(i, i + chunkSize)
    const timestreamParams = {
      DatabaseName: db_name,
      TableName: TimeSpanRawE[table_name],
      Records: chunk,
    }
    res.push(await writeClient.writeRecords(timestreamParams).promise())
  }

  ok(res)
} catch (error) {
  return err({ error, params })
}
```

but not the mix between them. If you really needed to, the `.catch(() => {}) // Silence error` needs to go on the promise that you are *not* `await`ing immediately (i.e. the ones you put in the array).

Answer (score 0):

I would put the retry logic in a separate function to make some separation of concerns. My usual way is to add to the `Promise`: `Promise.retry`.

Also your requests are independent from each other so you could execute them in parallel. We use `Array::map()` for that to get an array of promices

```js
async function retry(func, numberOfRetries = 1) {
    let error;
    do {
        try {
            return await func();
        } catch (e) {
            // some error logic would be nice
            error = e;
        }
    } while (--numberOfRetries);
    throw error;
}

const chunkSize = 100;

const requests = Records.reduce((chunks, item, index) =>
    ((chunks[Math.floor(index / chunkSize)] ??= []).push(item)) && chunks
    , [])
    .map(chunk => retry(writeRecords({
        DatabaseName: db_name,
        TableName: TimeSpanRawE[table_name],
        Records: chunk,
    }).promise()));

try {
    return Promise.all(requests).then((res) => ok(res))
} catch (error) {
    return err({ error, params })
}
```